# pandas read_csv complains "columns expected but not found" because of white space in headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas read_csv to load data into a table. the source file has delimiter as '|'. and column types are defined with DTYPES.
Because some headers in the source file have heading and trailing white spaces, like ' | '. the below program throws an error that columns defined in DTYPES are not found. How shall I work around this?

```
    data_file = pd.read_csv(
        file_path,
        sep='|',
        error_bad_lines=False,
        dtype=DTYPES,
        usecols= DTYPES.keys()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your column *separator* to recognize trailing whitespaces with regex pattern:

```
data_file = pd.read_csv(
    file_path,
    sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python',
    error_bad_lines=False,
    dtype=DTYPES,
    usecols= DTYPES.keys()
)
```

Comment: thanks! but after the change, none of the columns can find a match in usecols. Did I miss anything?        data_file = pd.read_csv(
            file_path,
            sep='\s*\|\s*', engine='python',
            error_bad_lines=False,
            dtype=DTYPES,
            usecols= DTYPES.keys()
        )

Comment: give a testable fragment of `file_path` and `DTYPES.keys()`